# Linux mint update error

Tags: linux

I just got some updates for my **linux mint** and when I try to install them a message like this appears:

```
Failed to fetch cdrom://Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release amd64 20131126/dists/saucy/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release amd64 20131126/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release amd64 20131126/dists/saucy/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release amd64 20131126/dists/saucy/contrib/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release amd64 20131126/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release amd64 20131126/dists/saucy/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: have you seen this? http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140110083437AAtIWmM

Answer (score 1):

Go to menu, scroll down to update manager, Login, click edit, then software sources, additional repositories, and then unselect "cdrom:[Linux. 
 Apparently,if you load the operating system from a dvd, as I did, this program will keep trying to load updates from the cdrom unit. However, if your system is like mine, the updates were still loading from the website, the error being generated only because the cdrom drive was tried first and of course there was no cd to be found.